# Can I Stop OCR on JPEG Files?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I have yet another hurdle to climb with my GOOGLE DRIVE SDK Android App. I am uploading scanned images with tightly controlled index fields - user defined 'tags' from local dictionary. For instance XXX.JPG has index words "car" + "insurance". Here is a simplified code snippet:

```
    ...
    body.setTitle("XXX.JPG");
    body.setDescription("car, insurance");        
    body.setIndexableText(new IndexableText().setText("car insurance"));
    body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
    body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(...)));

    FileContent cont = new FileContent("image/jpeg", new java.io.File(fullPath("xxx.jpg")));

    File gooFl = _svc.files().insert(body, cont).execute();
    ...
```

Again, everything works great, except when I start a search, I get results that apparently come from some OCR post process, thus rendering my system's DICTIONARY unusable. I assume I can use a custom MIME type, but then the JPEG images become invisible for users who use standard GOOGLE DRIVE application (local, browser-based ... ). So the question is: Can I upload MIME "image/jpeg" files with custom indexes (either Indexable, or Description fields) but stop GOOGLE from OCR-ing my files and adding indexes I did not intend to have?
Just to be more specific, I search for "car insurance" and instead of my 3 files I indexed this way, I get unmanageable pile of other results (JPEG scanned documents) that had "car" and "insurance" somewhere in them. Not what my app wants.
Thank you in advance, sean
...

Based on Burcu's advise below, I modified my code to something that looks like this (stripped to bare bones):

```
 // define meta-data
 File body = new File();
 body.setTitle("xxx.jpg");
 body.setDescription(tags);        
 body.setIndexableText(new IndexableText().setText(tags));
 body.setMimeType("image/jpeg");
 body.setParents(Arrays.asList(new ParentReference().setId(_ymID)));
 body.setModifiedDate(DateTime.parseRfc3339(ymdGOO));
 FileContent cont = 
    new FileContent("image/jpeg",new java.io.File(fullPath("xxx.jpg")));
 String sID = findOnGOO(driveSvc, body.getTitle());
 // file not found on gooDrive, upload and fix the date
 if (sID == null) { 
   driveSvc.files().insert(body, cont).setOcr(false).execute();
   driveSvc.files().patch(gooFl.getId(), body).setOcr(false).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute();
 // file found on gooDrive - modify metadata and/or body   
 } else {
   // modify content + metadata
   if (contentModified) {
    driveSvc.files().update(sID, body, cont).setOcr(false).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute(); 
   // only metadata (tags,...)
   } else {   
     driveSvc.files().patch(sID, body).setOcr(false).setSetModifiedDate(true).execute();
   }
 }
 ...
```

It is a block that uploads or modifies a Google Drive file. The two non-standard operations are:
1/ resetting the file's 'modified' date in order to force the date of file creation - tested, works OK
2/ stopping the OCR process that interferes with my apps indexing scheme - will test shortly and update here

For the sake of simplicity, I did not include the implementation of "findInGOO()" method. It is quite simple 2-liner and I can supply it upon request

sean

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On insertion, set the ocr parameter to false:

```
service.files().update(body, content).setOcr(false).execute();
```

Comment: I'm having such a hard time to get this thing done correctly since I can't easily translate the documentation into my java constructs. I've seen reference for [files:insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert), but could not figure out the correct java syntax. Also, the reference states the 'ocr' is 'false' by default. Go figure. I will test it and will let you know how it went. I have to catch you somewhere/sometime and buy you a beer. thanks again, sean

Comment: Thanks. OCR and useContentAsIndexableText is false by default and it's weird that we index extracted text. In the meanwhile, I will try to repro the problem here.

Comment: Burcu, if you are busy, you may let it sleep until I re-run another batch (some 500 files) with the '.setOcr(false)' switch. It will be no later than this week. Not many people are concerned about this, anyway.   BTW, is there a documentation somewhere that would translate the  HTTP based command syntax (like 'ocr') into the java '.setOcr()' methods. I am using Eclipse intelli-sense with mixed results. And you know, you helped me twice already. sean

Comment: And another thing popped up in my mind. The API documentation says OCR default for insert is 'false', but if you google (yes,the verb) "GOOGLE DRIVE OCR JPEG", you'll find a lot of statements - related more to user interaction with Google Drive (Drive App, Browser Drive Interface) stating that popular MIME types like pdf, jpeg... are indexed by default. It certainly implies indexing-OCRing by default (it is Google after all-synonymous with search). So the easiest solution would be just to change the documentation to 'true'. Am I pushing law breaking here?  sean

Comment: Google Drive upload also has an switch for not performing OCR on images. Front-end uses the same API, so their defaults are their defaults, programmatically overriding ours :)

Comment: Yep, I have tested it on the following 2 documents:

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxOS7mTBMR_bNDlsVjB4V3J4Qm8/edit?usp=sharing
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BxOS7mTBMR_bTUtEYWROd2t0bG8/edit?usp=sharing
with index tags 'vaccination' and 'certificate', but ended up with more than I asked for. For instance search for 'medical' will bring it as well. Some other switch that overrides application's is a misnomer. What is the app switch for, then? Anyway, it kills my (and possibly others' developers) effort to have our own indexing. So, conclusion is .setOcr(false) is a NO-GO !

Comment: Is it a bug? A feature? Do I have an official place to go and gripe about it? sean

Comment: Thanks for sharing an image. This is a bug. Sorry for that, it's in our backlog now. Google Drive UI doesn't work as expected either.

Comment: No problem for me at this time, I will push my directory of TAGs up to Drive, pull it down on the other side and construct the query myself. As a matter of fact my user will now have option to use my 'strict' dictionary search, or the 'loose' one from Google. That's what I meant by 'feature'. sean

Comment: ... and after 2 nights of tossing and turning, here is a slightly 'hacky', but easy solution. Prepend / append / twist / whatever ... your custom dictionary words (the ones that go into setIndexableText()) the way that they do not resemble anything meaningful. Do the same when searching, and BINGO, you should have your desired results. "There is no SW problem that can't be solved by yet another level of indirection". (Greg Colvin, Denver, 1990)